# What is the conditional compiler directive binded to Delphi XE4 compiler?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4, compiler-directives

What is the conditional compiler directive binded to Delphi XE4 compiler?
I though something like this:

```
{$ifdef VerDXE4}
  code segment compiled only by the Delphi XE4 compiler
{$endif}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `VER250`:

```
{$IFDEF VER250}
...
{$ENDIF}
```

Alternatively, you can use the [`CompilerVersion` constant](http://delphi.wikia.com/wiki/CompilerVersion_Constant):

```
{$IF (CompilerVersion >= 25) and (CompilerVersion < 26)}
...
{$IFEND}
```

Comment: The latter will only work from the Delphi version where "CompilerVersion" was introduced, whereas the first one will work in all versions of Delphi...

Comment: @HeartWare `CompilerVersion` (and `{$IF}`) was introduced in Delphi 6 over 20 years ago. You can use `{$IFDEF CONDITIONALEXPRESSIONS}` if you need to check if the compiler supports `{$IF}`

Comment: Yes, it was not a (negative) criticism, but just a heads-up to clarify. (and at the time of writing, it was "only" "more than 13 years ago" :-) )

Answer (score 5):

```
{$IFDEF VER250} // RAD Studio XE4
{$ENDIF}
```

The various versions are documented on Embarcadero's DocWiki:

[Delphi Compiler Versions](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Compiler_Versions)

Comment: The requested URL /RADStudio/berlin/en/Compiler_Versions was not found on this server.

Comment: Sorry, it works for me:  http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Berlin/en/Compiler_Versions

Comment: Better to use a version-agnostic url: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Compiler_Versions